# PhpExcel Formulas

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I'm working with PhpExcel 1.8.0 in Codeigniter 3.0.0, Codeigniter is running in WAPP Stack Server 5.4.39-0 (all of them should be the latest versions, i think).

This:

```
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G5', "SUMA(G1:G4)");
```

Displays the string "SUMA" in the downloaded file with the coordinates, but adding the "=" causes the server to answer with an error, which is interpreted by Chrome as "ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE".

The specified range is populated with integer values.

I'm not really used to Wapp, the Apache log files shows no relevant error for this issue, i would really appreciate to know a way i could debug this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SUMA` is not the "English Language" name for any Excel function.

Quoting from the PHPExcel documentation (the section entitled
[Write a formula into a cell](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#write-a-formula-into-a-cell))

> Inside the Excel file, formulas are always stored as they would appear in an English version of Microsoft Office Excel, and PHPExcel handles all formulae internally in this format. This means that the following rules hold:

- Decimal separator is '.' (period)
- Function argument separator is ',' (comma)
- Matrix row separator is ';' (semicolon)
- **English function names must be used**

(my emphasis)

If you want to use non-English function names in formulae, then read the appropriate section of the documentation on [Locale Settings for Formulae](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#locale-settings-for-formulae)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i mistakenly assumed that i should use the language of my Office installation, and an error like that drove me crazy haha.